# What cookies does Magento CE store by default?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, magento-community, cookie

There is some little info in the manual, but what cookies does Magento CE actually store during a visit?

In other words what does each cookie do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two main cookies are "adminhtml" and "frontend". Both of these cookies are what keeps track of your session (what is in your quote, are you logged in, etc).